# CSS stylesheet applies on some properties but not all

Tags: html, css

I have a css stylesheet that successfully changes the background color of the page. However, the properties I have set on my  and  tags do not work.

```
{% block body %}
    <div id='title'>
        <h1>
            VISUALIZER2D
        </h1>
    </div>
    <form class='formclass' action='/' method='post'>
        <div class='input'>
            <input name='link' placeholder='Enter YouTube URL' type ='text'>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type='submit'>Next</button>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

and my css stylesheet

```
body
{
    background-color: #252C3E;
    text-align: 'center';
    font-family: 'Courier'
}
.formclass
{
    border-radius: 8px;
}
.input
{
    font-size: 2em;
    height: 90px;
    width: 190px;
}
#title
{
    color: white;
}
```

Why is the background color the only property being applied?

Comment: Everything except text-align: 'center'; is fine, you don't see all the styles because of the background-color, like width, height, border-radius... And it's text-align: center; without quotes.

Comment: @VXp So if I don’t change the background colour the size of the form will change?

Comment: Background color has nothing to do with the size. Apply some bgc to .formclass and .input and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- || METADATA || -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <!-- || STYLESHEETS || -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      <!--
      Page
      title
      --
    />
    <title>Wtitle</title>

    <!-- || CSS || -->
    <style>
      body {
        padding: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #252c3e; /* Works | Changes background color */
        /* text-align: "center"; Invalid Property Value */
        font-family: "Courier"; /* Works | Changes font family */
      }
      .formclass {
        padding: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #73ad21;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 8px;
        width: 405px;
        text-align: left; /* Changes position of "Next" button */
      }
      .input {
        font-size: 2em;
        height: 90px;
        /* width: 195px; Don't need this */
      }
      #title {
        color: white;
        width: 410px;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- || BODY || -->
    <div id="title">
      <h1>
        VISUALIZER2D
      </h1>
    </div>
    <form class="formclass" action="/" method="post">
      <div class="input">
        <input name="link" placeholder="Enter YouTube URL" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit">Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- || METADATA || -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <!-- || STYLESHEETS || -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      <!--
      Page
      title
      --
    />
    <title>Wtitle</title>

    <!-- || CSS || -->
    <style>
      body {
        padding: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #252c3e; /* Works | Changes background color */
        /* text-align: "center"; Invalid Property Value */
        font-family: "Courier"; /* Works | Changes font family */
      }
      .formclass {
        padding: 5px;
        border: 2px solid #73ad21;
        background-color: white;
        border-radius: 8px;
        width: 405px;
        text-align: left; /* Changes position of "Next" button */
      }
      .input {
        font-size: 2em;
        height: 90px;
        /* width: 195px; Don't need this */
      }
      #title {
        color: white;
        width: 410px;
        text-align: center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- || BODY || -->
    <div id="title">
      <h1>
        VISUALIZER2D
      </h1>
    </div>
    <form class="formclass" action="/" method="post">
      <div class="input">
        <input name="link" placeholder="Enter YouTube URL" type="text" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit">Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Not sure exactly what you're going for, but I think this should help you get going in the right direction. It looks like you're trying to modify values that don't exist. You can round the edges of a border if there is no border. You have to create one for your form.

Comment: Thanks, just curious, what is the purpose of the bootstrap link in the href tag?

Comment: Was just using the library so I didn't have to manually do the basics while writing the code out is all. It can easily be removed.